# The outputs of the convolutional layer in Caffe are different

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

1. I wrote a siamese-like network using caffe with two inputs. The output of the convolutional layer with the first input is always the same, while the second output changes every time. The input layer and the convolutional layers are as follows:

> ```
> layer {
>   name: "input"
>   type: "Input"
>   top: "data1"
>   top: "data2"
>   input_param {
>     shape {dim: 1
>            dim: 1
>            dim: 28
>            dim: 28
>     }
>   }
> }
> layer {
>   name: "conv1"
>   type: "Convolution"
>   bottom: "data1"
>   top: "conv1_1"
>   convolution_param {
>     num_output: 20
>     kernel_size: 5
>     weight_filler {
>       type: "xavier"
>     }
>   }
> }
> layer {
>   name: "conv1"
>   type: "Convolution"
>   bottom: "data2"
>   top: "conv1_2"
>   convolution_param {
>     num_output: 20
>     kernel_size: 5
>     bias_term: false
>     weight_filler {
>       type: "xavier"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

2. May I build the convolutional layer with the python layer? If so, how

Comment: How do you feed the data into the network? What do you mean with 2 - creating this network with pycaffe instead of manually writing a `.prototxt` file?

Comment: @hbaderts Sorry about the loss of some words after I submitted the question. I mean how I should pass the weights and biases when I rewrite the convolutional layer by using the Python Layer, whose type is "Python" in the .prototxt file. As to the input data, I tried to create two nets at the same time. "data1" and "data2" were fed into the two nets respectively.